# Unable to display data in DataTable from a server via ajax

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, datatables

I want to display data in DataTable via ajax from a server. Here's what I have:

```
 # server
  # ....
  return jsonify({"data": {1: (123, "something1", 333), 2: (456, "something2", 555)}})
```

And a template:

```
<script>
    $("#my_table").DataTable({
      ajax: "/my_url.json",
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      columns: [
        {data: "id" },
        {data: "column2"},
        {data: "column3"}
      ] 
    });
  </script>
```

And a table:

```
<table id="my_table">
  <thead>
   ......
```

For some reason, nothing happens. At all. Neither an ajax request to a server. Nor errors either. The js and css files have been included into the template.

When I go to "/my_url.json" in a browser, it returns json.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to adapt your server-side script a little as DataTables expects the data to be in this form:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 123, 
            "column2": "something1", 
            "column3": 333
        },{
            "id": 456, 
            "column2": "something2", 
            "column3": 555
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm pretty sure that your data won't be in that sort of format, though well done for clocking the need for `data`!

I'm not up on Python so I'm not sure how you'd go about altering your server-side script, sorry. You could process it within DataTables but it might be better to do it server-side, hope that helps.

Comment: actually, 'data' is not completely necessary. You can specify what is the key containing the data using the [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option

Comment: I know, but as I was writing my response `data` got added and it is required unless you want to add `dataSrc` and thus changing the `ajax` to an object rather than just a URI. But I should've mentioned that, you're right.